# Expanding border bottom with focus on text input

Tags: html, css

I would like to make this `border-bottom` still visible when `input` is on `focus`.

```css
.expand input {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: #eee;
}

.expand {
  display: inline-block;
}

.expand:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 3px solid #2bcf67;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin:  0% 50%;
}

.expand:focus:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="expand" tabindex="0">
  <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Your text">
  Click here
</div>

<p>I would like to have same effect but clicking on text input</p>
```

Comment: You can't, that would require a parent selector, which is something CSS doesn't have. It requires a dirty fix.

Comment: @mdm Without a surrounding div that's impossible in pure CSS (because not even pseudo-elements can be used on *input*). However that can be achieved with jQuery, I can help you with that if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<input>` element can not have pseudoelements, but you can use a dummy `<div>` element to be a border for you: http://jsfiddle.net/QrrpB/2492/

```css
.expand input {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
}

.expand {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.border {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  background: #2bcf67;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin:  0% 50%;
}

input:focus + .border, .expand:focus .border {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="expand" tabindex="0">
  <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Your text">
  <div class="border"></div>
  click
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Pseudo-elements` are only supported on `container` elements. Because the way they are rendered are within the container itself as a child element. `input` cannot contain other elements hence they're not supported.

Here is the [W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content) for how to use Pseudo-elements

Answer (score 0):

So instead of having to wrap every `input` in an **expand div**, jQuery does that for you now, here: http://jsfiddle.net/QrrpB/2467/

P.s: Hope I understood right what you wanted.

Comment: I would like to make this `border-bottom` still visible when `input` will be on `focus`. Even with using `div`. Sorry if I didn't explain this clearly :)

Comment: so you want the effect both on **hover and focus** or solely **focus** ?

Comment: only on **focus**